# Complex Line Integral of Holomorphic Function over Closed Curve is Zero

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working on the following problem:

Let $f$ be holomorphic on an open set $U$ which is the interior of a disk or a rectangle. Let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow U$ be a $C^1$ curve satisfying $\gamma (0) = \gamma(1)$. Prove that
$$ \oint_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$$

My attempt:

Now, since $U$ is either an open disk or open rectangle and $f$ is holomorphic on $U$, $\exists H$ on $U$ s.t. 
$$ \frac{\partial H}{\partial z} \equiv F$$
on U. Since $\gamma$ is a closed curve, it follows that
$$ H(\gamma (1)) - H(\gamma (0)) = 0.$$
Further, since $H$ is holomorphic on U, we also have that
\begin{align*}
H(\gamma (1)) - H(\gamma (0)) &= \oint_\gamma \frac{\partial H}{\partial z} (z) dx \\
&= \oint_\gamma f(z) dz \\
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$ \oint_\gamma f(z)dz = 0 $$

My qualm about this problem is that it seems like we are just proving the Cauchy Integral Formula, but now we're allowing $U$ to be an open rectangle. I don't seem to use this fact except in the first step, in concluding that, in either the case of $U$ being an open disk or open rectangle, $f$ being holomorphic guarantees a holomorphic antiderivative on $U$. Is this the only part of the proof where this comes into play?

Comment: One first proves Cauchy's theorem and uses it prove the existence of your $H$. This statement and its proof don't makes much sense to me. You have to tell us what results can be used to prove that $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\, dz=0$. Otherwise, the question may be deleted for being out of context.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy actually the convexity of the domain plays a role on defining the primitive without invoking Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a restricted version of [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem). And in order to prove it we use the Cauchy-Riemann equations together with [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), since $\gamma$ is $C^1$ and $U$ is simply connected in both cases. For a general simply connected $U$, this implies the existence of $H$ not the other way around.

However, in these special cases, $U$ is a **convex set**, in particular star-shaped, and the primitive $H$ can be furnished applying the [Poincaré Lemma](https://www.math.brown.edu/~res/M114/notes7.pdf) to $\omega = f(z)dz$, which is closed by Cauchy-Riemann equations. Clearly the existence of a primitive solves the problem.

Therefore, the special choice for $U$ is used to ensure the existence of a primitive without invoking Cauchy's theorem.